# Module Wavelink Has no attribute Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
import wavelink
from discord.ext import commands
#Please help me 


class Bot(commands.Bot):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Bot, self).__init__(command_prefix=['audio ', 'wave ','aw '])

    self.add_cog(Music(self))

  async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'Logged in as {self.user.name} | {self.user.id}')


class Music(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

    if not hasattr(bot, 'wavelink'):
        self.bot.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.bot)

    self.bot.loop.create_task(self.start_nodes())

  async def start_nodes(self):
     await self.bot.wavelink.initiate_node(host='lava.link',
                                          port=2333,
                                          rest_uri='http://lava.link:2333',
                                          password='youshallnotpass',
                                          identifier='TEST',
                                          region='us_east')

  @commands.command(name='connect')
  async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    if not chan`enter code here`nel:
        try:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        except AttributeError:
            raise discord.DiscordException('No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.')

    player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
    await ctx.send(f'Connecting to **`{channel.name}`**')
    await player.connect(channel.id)

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):
    tracks = await self.bot.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{query}')

    if not tracks:
        return await ctx.send('Could not find any songs with that query.')

    player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
    if not player.is_connected:
        await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

    await ctx.send(f'Added {str(tracks[0])} to the queue.')
    await player.play(tracks[0])
    #play music

bot = Bot()
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

but it is showing an error when running

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Cogs/music2.py", line 62, in 
bot = Bot()
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Cogs/music2.py", line 11, in **init**
self.add_cog(Music(self))
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Cogs/music2.py", line 23, in **init**
self.bot.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.bot)
AttributeError: module 'wavelink' has no attribute 'Client'

It would be helpful if anybody help me

Please help me??

Comment: Please post your codes, errors in the question.

Comment: Please post your codes, errors in the question.

Comment: Please check now